# WOOCOMMERCE - Creating "Total Weight" column (for each product in cart)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Could someone help me with getting Total Weight instead of weight of a product in separate column. I'm stuck on:

```
<td class="product-weight">
<?php
 echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_weight', $_product>get_weight()); echo "g";
?>
</td>
```

Which is giving me just a weight. What I need is - example: if someone will buy 10 sausages (100grams each) I need to get an 1000 grams output in next column.